# ¿Por qué entra al if(isset()){}?

Tags: php, condiciones

Html:

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="categoria" value="Websites">
  <button type="submit">Websites</button>
</form>
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="categoria" value="Games">
  <button type="submit">Games</button>
</form>
```

Cuando ejecuta, no hace caso al `if` y sigue apareciendo como si nada,

Aquí mi `PHP`:

```
<?php

        if(isset($_GET['categoria']) == "Websites"){
        ?>
        <article id="ArtWebSite Oculto" class="">
            <form action="?view=buscarW" role="search" method="POST">
                <div class="divSearch">   
                    <input type="text" name="busqueda" placeholder="Search about the programing Websites" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
            </form>
        </article>
        <?php
        }

        if(isset($_GET['categoria']) == "Games"){
        ?>
        <article id="ArtGames Oculto" class="">
            <form action="?view=buscarG" role="search" method="POST">
                <div class="divSearch">   
                    <input type="text" name="busqueda" placeholder="Search about the Games" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
            </form>
        </article>
        <?php
        }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es pues el problema o error?

Comment: Espera voy a reeditar

Comment: Simplemente tienes mal formulado el if, intenta `if(isset($_GET['categoria']) && $_GET['categoria']  == "Websites")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `isset` devuelve un `bool` y eso es lo que estás comparando con el `string` "Websites" o "Games", ambas expresiones van a dar siempre verdadero.

Deberías escribirlo así:

```
if (isset($_GET['categoria']) && $_GET['categoria'] == "Websites")
```

Es decir chequeas si existe y si es igual a "Websites".

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe a que [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php):

> Devuelve `TRUE` si `var` existe y tiene un valor distinto de `NULL`, `FALSE` de lo contrario.

Y en `PHP`, al validar si `true` es igual (`==`) a cualquier cosa distinta de vacío (`eg: "", []`), `NULL` o `false`, es `true`.

### Solución:

Usa `isset` para saber si la variable existe y por separado compara su valor.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['categoria'])){
    if($_GET['categoria'] == "Websites"){
  ?>
  <article id="ArtWebSite Oculto" class="">
      <form action="?view=buscarW" role="search" method="POST">
          <div class="divSearch">   
              <input type="text" name="busqueda" placeholder="Search about the programing Websites" required>
          </div>
          <button type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
      </form>
  </article>
  <?php
    }
    else if($_GET['categoria'] == "Games"){
  ?>
  <article id="ArtGames Oculto" class="">
      <form action="?view=buscarG" role="search" method="POST">
          <div class="divSearch">   
              <input type="text" name="busqueda" placeholder="Search about the Games" required>
          </div>
          <button type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
      </form>
  </article>
  <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Sólo cambiaría el segundo `if` por un `elseif`.